# what event triggers youtube iframe to show controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, triggers, youtube

I have a youtube iframe with a div with the same size on top of it. Usually when a mouse enters the youtube iframe, the youtube control bar is automatically shown. However because of the overlaying div, this event is not triggering. So I am trying to trigger this event whenever the mouse enters the overlaying div using jquery.

The problem is that I can't seem to figure out what event triggers the control bar to show (or even if what I want is possible). I have tried hover, mouseenter/mouseleave, but to no avail...

Comment: The event is happening on the document inside the iframe, you do not have access to said document. therefore, there is no solution other than not having a div overlay it.

Comment: Cheers dude, just if anyone else is in a similar situation, I ended up compromising  and making the overlaying div smaller and "centered" in the iframe. Hence the iframe still detects a mouse entering and leaving it and I still have most of the iframe covered.